# Collapsing strings from same column into one cell depending on other columns

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, string-aggregation

I have a column in my data (loc) with string values, which I'd like to collapse into one cell/row, per vso/type combination. This is what I currently have:

```
SELECT vso, type, mp, loc, qty
FROM main

vso type mp   loc      qty
D13  S   UK   CW1     29252
D13  S   DE   FR6      5799
D13  N   UK   CW1        38
D13  N   DE   FR1         9
```

The output I want:

```
vso type   loc        total_qty
D13  S     CW1, FR6     35324
D13  N     CW1, FR1       47
```

I guess the basic setup would be something like this:

```
SELECT vso, type, SUM(qty) as total_qty, [some sort of concat function of loc]
FROM [table above]
GROUP BY vso, type
```

But I'm not sure what to do about the loc column. Ideally, if the loc values per vso and per type are identical, I would only want one of them displayed, not the duplicates.

I'm doing this in AWS Redshift, by the way.

Comment: I think you are looking for the `LISTAGG()` function.

Answer (score 2):

use listagg

```
SELECT vso, type, SUM(qty) as total_qty, listagg(loc ,', ') 
within group (order by type)
FROM [table above]
GROUP BY vso, type
```